# Docusign error unauthorized_client when trying to generate the access token

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Docusign REST API collection.  Following the videos to set up and get access token.  I successfully get the code from this URL:
[https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={clientID}&redirect_uri={URL}](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=%7BclientID%7D&redirect_uri=%7BURL%7D)

I take the code returned, place it into my {codeFromURL} variable.  I click on submit.  I get an unauthorized_client error.

I verified the integration key, secret key were correctly encoded and used in the header authorization.

I searched everywhere.  I can not figure out how to fix and get past this error.  I am hoping someone on hear will be of some help.

Here is the snippet shown by postman. I replaced some of the values with asterisks for privacy.

POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: account-d.docusign.com
Authorization: Basic Y2VmMDkxODktOWU4Yi00YzZhL******
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 708

code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2I*******&grant_type=authorization_code

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes of this error can be:
"1- Valid integration key and Secret Key were replaced in Authorization: "Basic encodedBase64(integrationKey:SecretKey)" so it's the actual values you obtained from your DocuSign Developer Account. (the way you had the quotes suggest you have this as a string value without the actual values encoded).
2- The code is valid for 2 minutes only.
3- The same IK that was used to obtain the code is used in the header."

If the problem persisted after you verified these 3 possible root cause, thanks to open a ticket support to Docusign, in order we could make further research based on your Ids